# What is the difference between Array.GetLength() and Array.Length?

Tags: c#, arrays

How do you use the `Array.GetLength` function in C#?

What is the difference between the `Length` property and the `GetLength` function?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`GetLength` takes an integer that specifies the dimension of the array that you're querying and returns its length. `Length` property returns the total number of items in an array:

```
int[,,] a = new int[10,11,12];
Console.WriteLine(a.Length);           // 1320
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(0));     // 10
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(1));     // 11
Console.WriteLine(a.GetLength(2));     // 12
```

Comment: And on one-dimensional arrays `Length` will return the same value as `GetLength(0)`.

Comment: Why is a.GetLength(2) 11 and not 12?

Comment: @Mike: Cause 1 and 2 are a single key away.

Comment: Why is a.Length 1320?

Why are the a.GetLength values, simply their values?  

This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Neo42 1320=10x11x12

Answer (score 16):

For 1-dimensional arrays `Length` and `GetLength(0)` are exactly the same.

For arrays of higher rank `Length` is the product of all `GetLength(0..Rank-1)` values, in other words it is always the total number of fields.

Comment: int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3 , 4}
is testArray.GetLength(1) correct?

Comment: No. Should be `testArray.GetLength(0)`.

Comment: divo, "jagged arrays" are arrays of arrays, at each level rank==1. They are not multi-dimensional in the same way.

Answer (score 10):

The `.Length` property returns the number of elements in an array, whether it be one dimensional or multidimensional. That is a 2x6 array will have length of 12.

The `.GetLength(0)` method returns number of elements in the row direction in a multidimensional array. For a 2x6 array that is 2.

The `.GetLength(1)` method returns number of elements in the column direction in a multidimensional array. For a 2x6 array that is 6.

These do not return an actual element value, as stated by the chosen answer above.

Answer (score 4):

GetLength returns the length of a specified dimension of a mulit-dimensional array.

Length returns the sum of the total number of elements in all the dimensions.

- For a single-dimensional array, Length == GetLength(0)
- For a two-dimensional array, Length == GetLength(0) * GetLength(1)

etc.

Comment: Not quite true: Two dimensional arrays: Length = GetLength(0) * GetLength(1)

Comment: That's a clever typo! How did I manage to transpose + and * ?! (fixed)

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical term, we call as m rows and n columns, so the results is product of m*n for a two dimensional array. In this case  `GetLength(0) = m` rows and  `GetLength(1)= n` columns. For e.g see below example

```
string[,] stocks ={{"RELIND","Reliance Industries","1006.30"},{"TATMOB","Tata Mobiles","504.10"},{"ALST","Allstate","800.00"}, {"GE","GE Motors","810.00"}
};
```

The stocks arrays return `GetLength(0)= 4` and `GetLength(1)=3` and `length =12`

Comment: GetLength(0)= 3 and GetLength(1)=2. It returns the index(which starts from zero) of the element, not the actual element count. I was confused by this for a minute. so I had to clarify.